# using substring in concat operation in XPath/XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

is this good practice/allowed in XSLT?

```
<xsl:variable name="fullName" select="normalize-space(concat($person/name/first,' ',substring($person/name/middle,1,1),'.',' ',$person/name/last))"/>
```

I am trying to grab concatenate the following:

```
person/name/first=John
person/name/middle=Mulcair
person/name/last=Howard
```

into

```
#fullName=John M. Howard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly allowed and in XSLT 1.0 it is the usual approach. In XSLT 2.0 (as available with Saxon 9 for Java) you can use `$person/name/concat(first, ' ', substring(middle,1,1), '. ', last)` and with XSLT 3.0 (as available with Saxon 9.6 for Java) you can use `||` e.g. `$person/name/(first || ' ' || substring(middle, 1, 1) || '. ' || last)`.